# Pip version can't be displayed from cmd terminal

Tags: python, pip

Sorry for the simple question (I am brand new to this)

I'm currently using Python 3.7. It came with pip installed automatically but I am unable to get it to display the current version from CMD (I use windows 10)

However, in the Pycharm terminal it works perfectly. I don't know why everyone says "pip --version" should work in CMD. I tried it and it didn't work.

What could be the cause?

I've tried using the same commands everyone else uses to display current pip version.

location for pip installment is C:\Users\"Username"\Desktop\untitled\venv\Scripts

when i run pip --version or just pip it says in cmd 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Running cmd as admin didn't help either.

It's not a crisis considering the fact that pip works and i get the package system and the imports running after i did the commands in the pycharm terminal. I'm just looking for a reason as to why it's unable to find the pip in the "normal" cmd versus the pycharm built in terminal.

Comment: We cannot see your screen. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Does just `python` in cmd work? Has the directory where `pip.exe` is located been added to the path?

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. As @Blorgbeard eloquently put: we cant see what you see, so _tell us what you see._ "It didn't work" isn't helpful.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer and then trying again? ...seriously, if you only recently installed python, some of the changes it made to the environment might not stick until the environment reconstructs itself after rebooting.

Comment: I updated it with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Python 3.7 to your PATH (environment variables)? Windows may not be able to access pip or its coupled commands unless you do.

The two methods of accessing the pip version from the Windows Terminal (i.e. CMD) or Windows Powershell are as follows:

> pip --version

and

> pip -V

Give those two a shot again, and make sure that Python 3.7 is part of your system PATH.